# javascript: validate number of characters added, removed and modified in textbox

Tags: javascript

I want to validate number of characters added, removed and modified in text-box.

Below is the code for validate characters modified:

```
function charModified(currentValue,actualValue) {
    var charModified=0;
    var iterationLength = Math.min(currentValue.length,actualValue.length);
    for(var j=0;j<iterationLength;j++) {
        if(currentValue.charAt(j)!=actualValue.charAt(j)) {
            charModified++;
        }

    }
    if(charModified>3) {
            alert("more than 3 charcters are modified ");
    }
     return charModified;
```

}

Below is the code for validate characters AddedRemoved:

```
function charAddedRemoved(actualValueLength,currentValueLength) {
var numberOfCharcters = 0;

    if(actualValueLength>currentValueLength)    {
        numberOfCharcters = actualValueLength- currentValueLength;
    }
    if(currentValueLength>actualValueLength)    {
        numberOfCharcters = currentValueLength - actualValueLength;
    }
    if(numberOfCharcters>3) {
        alert("Added/Removed more than 3 Characters ");
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you have a question about your code?

Comment: The *charModified* function doesn't seem very accurate. Deleting a single character will mean all subsequent characters don't align with their original positions so all will be reported as being modified. In function *charAddedRemoved*, where is *actualFirstNameLength* defined or initialised?

Comment: When i will submit the page, then i want to validate if more than 3 characters are Added, removed and changed then show an alert message.

Comment: Perhaps you have a form. Then you will need to use a [*submit listener*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#dom-form-submit) on the form that returns false if it fails validation to cancel the submit. Otherwise, it will submit. Something like `<form onsubmit="return doValidation(this)" ...>`. Search here, there are many examples.

Comment: yes, but i want correct validation function, to validate textbox value.